# Using JSch with a SSL connection to HAProxy with SSH server backend

Tags: java, ssl, ssh, haproxy, jsch

There is a need to utilize a SSL connection to HAProxy.  Normally from the command line this is done with

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="openssl s_client -quiet -connect 172.16.0.10:2222 -servername 192.168.0.201 -cert mycert.crt -key mykey.key" _dummyhost_
```

where `openssl` creates the connection to the proxy server.

How would you accomplish this with JSch in order to connect to the proxy server?

Comment: I may have found my answer in using setSocketFactory to create the connection.  any example of this would be helpful.

Comment: Please can you tell us what's JSch is?

Comment: @Aleksandar See the tag [tag:jsch].